# Is there a payment gateway out there to work with this business model?

Tags: payment-gateway, gateway

I'm working on a site that allows people to list items for sale, but they don't have to pay for the listing until the item sells. I've looked through the Paypal and Amazon API, but don't see a way to authorize a payment for an unverified amount, and charge at what could be a much later date (months later). Paypal allows for authorization, to capture later, but the final amount cannot be more than 15% of the authorization amount. My problem is that the amount will not be known. Paypal also only allows you to delay charging for up to 29 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All credit card authorizations expire after ~30 days if the payment isn't completed.  So you'll have to go with a PCI compliant remote credit card storage provider, for example, [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/)

You could also just store the user's Paypal account, and send a bill to it when it sells.

Comment: Yeah, we are hoping to stay away from PCI compliance. The Amazon payment API may have what we need, or maybe we can work within this somehow http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAggregatedGuide/. Thanks

Comment: You're probably right about that.  Jungledisk charges me for *months* after they've authorized a chunk of cash.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to do this is to charge up front, but refund if it hasn't sold after X weeks?